# Program cannot run due to no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I get an error of "no operator matches these operands" when using the part of the code `outputFile << customerName << "your Monthly payments are " << monthlyPay << endl;`.  Overall, I need the code to Add the ability to save data to disk in one or more files and a menu should give the user the option to save or retrieve data.  I have not gotten past the error to properly run the program.  Can you please help fix error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <vector>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void menu(void);
void writeData(void);
void readData(void);

const char FileName[] = "CourseProjectAvilaF.txt";

//Variables
vector <double> Loanlgth, Loanamt, interestRate, totalInterest;
vector <double> monthlyPay(100), loanTotal(100), creditScore(100);
vector <string> customerName;


int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(void)
{
    const int INPUT_CUSTOMER = 1, DISPLAY_LOAN = 2, EXIT_PROGRAM = 3;
    int option;

    //Program
    cout << "Thank you for choosing The Bank of UA for your loan requirements!\n\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "UA Bank menu:\n\n"
            << "1. Enter your information\n"
            << "2. See your loan requirements\n"
            << "3. Exit program\n\n"
            << "Choose an option: ";
        cin >> option;
        while (option < INPUT_CUSTOMER || option > EXIT_PROGRAM)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid menu option: ";
            cin >> option;
        }
        if (option == 1)
        {
            writeData();
        }
        if (option == 2)
        {
            readData();
        }

    } while (option != EXIT_PROGRAM);

}



//function to read customer information
void writeData(void)
{
    fstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(FileName, fstream::app);
    int index;
    int numCustomers = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the number of customers you would like\n"
        << " to enter loan information for: ";
    cin >> numCustomers;

    for (index = 0; index < numCustomers; index++)
    {
        string tempName;
        double tempLoanamt, tempLoanlgth, tempcreditScore, tempinterestRate,
            tempinterest;

        cout << "Please enter your name: ";
        cin >> tempName;
        customerName.push_back(tempName);
        cout << "Please enter the loan amount: $";
        cin >> tempLoanamt;
        Loanamt.push_back(tempLoanamt);
        cout << "Please enter the length of the loan in months: ";
        cin >> tempLoanlgth;
        Loanlgth.push_back(tempLoanlgth);
        cout << "What is your current credit score? ";
        cin >> tempcreditScore;
        creditScore.push_back(tempcreditScore);
        //This will determine interest rate and overall loan amount when calculated
        if (tempcreditScore <= 650)
            tempinterestRate = .12;
        else
            tempinterestRate = .05;
        interestRate.push_back(tempinterestRate);

        //Calculations
        tempinterest = Loanamt[index] * interestRate[index];
        totalInterest.push_back(tempinterest);
        loanTotal[index] = (Loanamt[index] + totalInterest[index]);
        monthlyPay[index] = loanTotal[index] / Loanlgth[index];


        // Out put files to write data to be saved

        outputFile << customerName << "your Monthly payments are " << monthlyPay << endl;                                           
        outputFile << "Your total interest is " << totalInterest << endl;                           
        outputFile << "You owe " << loanTotal << endl;                                          
        outputFile << "You have " << Loanlgth << " months to pay off your balance" << endl;

    }

    outputFile.close(); //Close file
}

//function loan information
void readData(void)
{
    int index;
    int numCustomers = 0;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(FileName, fstream::in);//Open the file with read mode
    //Display monthly payment
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    for (index = 0; index < numCustomers; index++)
    {
        cout << customerName[index] << " your total loan is " << loanTotal[index]
            << "\n"
            << "with a monthly payment of $" << monthlyPay[index] << "\n"
            << "for " << Loanlgth[index] << " months with an interest\n"
            << "rate of " << interestRate[index] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future why not copy and paste the exact error message. They often tell an experienced programmer *exactly* what went wrong, with variable types and details.

Comment: For example in this one it would be `cpp-test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cpp-test.cpp:8:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
   cout << v;
   ~~~~~^~~~
` but don't include the following two pages of notes about possible templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple enough, you got it right everywhere else in your program.

When you want to access a particular element of a vector you use an *index*. Like this

```
    outputFile << customerName[index] << "your Monthly payments are " << monthlyPay[index] << endl;                                           
    outputFile << "Your total interest is " << totalInterest[index] << endl;                           
    outputFile << "You owe " << loanTotal[index] << endl;                                          
    outputFile << "You have " << Loanlgth[index] << " months to pay off your balance" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`customerName` and `monthlyPay` are `vector`s. You can't stream them directly. Instead you can do something like

```
for (auto const &name : customerName)
  outputFile << name;
```